# Firebase push notification vs childAdd listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working in a friend request module for mobile app base on Firebase so I'm considering to choose the way that notification is pushed.

Assume that userA request to be friend with userB. There're 2 ideas now:
- userA send request to a simple server then it will call FCM to send notification to userB.
- Make a service that listen to data changed in Firebase realtime database then userA will make change on that db and notification will be shown on userB device.

I think both are possible to implement but what is better, and why?
Please give me some advice about this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using either one should be fine.

However, a point to consider here is when keeping a listener active for the Real-time database, it also keeps an open socket on the user's device which adds to battery consumption.

While for FCM, it will only trigger once there is a notification is needed to be sent. If a *friend request* isn't really that app critical, I think using FCM is a way to go.

Have you also considered using both? If the user is currently online, it would be good to use the Real-time DB, but the `childAdded` won't be triggered if the user is offline (*not using the app for instance*). In that case, you can set it so that a notification will be sent to the user.

The important thing in your scenario is that the *friend request* should be saved first in your database or app server, so that it will trigger the corresponding action (FCM notification or Real-time DB update).

Comment: Thank you for your response, AL. As I've mentioned before, the childAdded will be listened in a Service, so when user is offline, it still be triggered as well. But yes, the point is when childAdded, every user will catch it but we just need a minor check to skip it. And FCM use a service also. I think I need more test to check which is better :P

Comment: I see. I missed that part on the `childAdded`. I guess either one should still be fine. So long as the *friend request* is delivered. Good luck with your app. Cheers!

Comment: I'd like to vote up for your answer but my reputation has not enough yet lol.  Additional, if I update database inside user record (as a field named "requested" for example), only that user receive the notification without checking. Again, thank you very much ;)

Comment: No worries. You'll get there soon enough. :D I think you're idea with the `requested` field is OK. Are you planning to make it a list of `request`s? So that you'll just retrieve the list then show it to the user, then delete if already seen or responded to.?

Comment: Haha, right, that's what i'm going to get. Problem now is how I put it in my code :D